# Passing parameters to SSRS query with Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, parameters, database-connection, reportbuilder

I have PostgreSQL database and I am trying to make a SSRS report via ReportBuilder from the database. I installed ODBC and made a data source to connect to it. It works fine and I can make DataSets from queries, but the problem comes if I want to pass a parameter in the query. For example if I make a query "Select * from public."Person" limit 100" it works fine also if I hardcode a parameter like "Select * from public."Person" where "CreatorUserId" = 15 limit 100" it works fine as well , but if I try to pass a parameter like "Select * from public."Person" where "CreatorUserId" = @CreatorUserId limit 100", I get the following error
[image: .] I suspect that the problem is because The column names in my PostgreSQL database are with capital letters. For example this column name is  "CreatorUserId". I also have registered the parameter in report builder and tryied to get it as input field and from another dataset but same error appears again. My question is is there a way for me to use a query and pass parameters while using a postgresql db, and if the capital letter is not the issu what is the possible solution for this.

Comment: Not sure about PostgreSQL in particular, but I think it needs to use a **?** instead of @CreatorUserId for the parameter with ODBC. `WHERE CreatorUserId = ?` The lowercase error is confusing tho.

Comment: Thank you verry much, Works with "?"..What happens if there are multiple parameters, does the order matters?

Comment: Correct - it goes by the order. If you (re-)use many parameters, you might want to define your own in the query `DECLARE @START_DATE DATE = ?`